# Will setx command work in windows xp?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, windows-xp

```
@echo off
SETX -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31"
pause
```

- I tried setting javahome using setx in windows xp with the help of batch file. but it didn't work

will setx work in windows xp sp3? and how to run command prompt as admin in xp?

Answer (score 4):

1. `SETX` is not a native windows XP command, but it comes with the **Support Tools** CD of Windows XP Pro. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546

   try `SETX /?` in the command line and read the online help
2. Use `RUNAS` command to run a program with administrator privileges. See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

   For starting a command prompt with administrator privileges, `RUNAS /user:HERO cmd.exe`

Answer (score 3):

`setx`
 Download Page: [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).
Command Line Syntax: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
SS64: Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU) [Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

---

`setx` help message:

```
SETX: This program is used to set values in the environment
of the machine or currently logged on user using one of three modes.

1) Command Line Mode: setx variable value [-m]
   Optional Switches:
    -m  Set value in the Machine environment. Default is User.

2) Registry Mode: setx variable -k hive\key\...\value
   Optional Switches:
    -m  Set value in the Machine environment. Default is User.

3) File Mode: setx variable -f file {-a x,y | -r x,y "string"} [-d d] [-x] [-m]
   Required Switches:
    -f  file         : Specify file name to use.
    -a  x,y          : Specify absolute coordinates and offset.
    -r  x,y "string" : Specify coordinates and offset relative to string.
   Optional Switches
    -d  ,:\ etc.  : Specify additional delimiters.
    -x            : Displays file coordinates. Switches -a -r -e ignored!!
    -m            : Set value in the Machine environment. Default is User.
```

---

`setx` examples message:

```
SETX Examples:
--------------
To view the examples screen best set the width of your command window to 100.

For the file type examples you must first create the file that you wish to
parse by using "command > filename" ie ipconfig > ipconfig.out.

IMPORTANT: SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.
Variables set using SETX are only available in future command windows and not
in the current command window.



SETX Command Line Examples:
--------------------------
SETX MACHINE COMPAQ
Sets value of MACHINE to be COMPAQ in the users environment.

SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" -m
Sets value of MACHINE to be "COMPAQ COMPUTER" in the machine environment.

SETX MYPATH %PATH%
Sets the value of MYPATH to the CURRENT value of the PATH environment variable.

SETX MYPATH ~PATH~
Sets the value of MYPATH to ALWAYS be equal to the value of the PATH environment
variable even in the event that the PATH variable changes.



SETX Registry Examples:
-------------------
SETX TZONE -k HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\StandardName
Sets the value of TZONE to the above key ie. "Central Standard Time"

SETX BUILD -k "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber"
Sets the value of BUILD to the current Windows NT build ie. "1314"
Note: Quotes must be used because of the embedded space in "Windows NT".



SETX File Examples:
-------------------
SETX VAR -f ipconfig.out -x
Displays the coordinates for the contents of the file "ipconfig.out".

SETX IPADDR -f ipconfig.out -a 5,11
Finds value at absolute offset 5,11 of the file ipconfig.out
Sets IPADDR to the IP Address (absolute offset 5,11)

SETX OCTET1 -f ipconfig.out -a 5,3 -d .
Finds value at absolute offset 5,3 and uses "." as an additional delimiter.
Sets OCTET1 to the first octet of the IP Address

SETX IPGATEWAY -f ipconfig.out -r 0,7 "Gateway"
Finds value at relative offset 0,7 to the keyword "Gateway"
Sets IPGATEWAY to the first octet of the IP Address
```

Comment: the problem is not resolved. that's why accepting answer is in pending. will support tools create an entry in registry after its installation?

Comment: @BobbyRachel    scanning registries is **not** part of the question and answer. Enhancment of questions is against the SO rules, you have to make a new question instead.

Comment: @BobbyRachel added some useful information for your convenience :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a new tool witch works very fine and have unique features and solve all setx problems: [regenv](https://github.com/lunakid/regenv)

- it works in xp+.
- it is better than setx ,pathed, pathman, setenv

```sh
set "var=D:\Bin"

:: ::::: override a system var:
regenv.exe set -nS c "%var%"

:: ::::: append to a system var
regenv.exe set -nS -sa c "%var%"

:: ::::: preppend to a system var
regenv.exe set -nS -sp c "%var%"

:: ::::: create a variable that contain an unexpanded variable
regenv.exe set -nS -sp c "%%var%%"

:: ::::: Note about PATH: if you edit PATH it is good to use -x , because -x will convert the reg type from REG_SZ to REG_EXPAND_SZ, because some tools may create a REG_SZ while the default reg type for PATH is REG_EXPAND_SZ
regenv.exe set -nS -sp -x PATH "%var%"
```

it can even create Volatile variables (HKCU\Volatile Environment).

see this for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx/1678250#1678250